# Dualboot (10.5.8/XP) MacBook freezes at startup

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot

My MacBook freezes at the boot screen

[image]

The wheel is *not* spinning.

I can however do the following:

- Hold down alt and select if I want to boot Mac OS X or Windows XP
- Start windows in safe mode, if I try to start windows normally the computer hangs on windows loading screen.
- Boot the Mac OS X in safe mode (what I'm running now).

What could be wrong and how can I diagnose/fix the error?

Comment: I think you should move this to Apple.SE. Flag it and request for it to be migrated.

Comment: @daviesgeek You're wrong. Except for personal preference, there is no reason to go there. And it's clear from your reputation that you like Apple.SE better; but that's no reason to send others there.

Comment: The question is on topic here on Super User, and because Windows is involved, it would be better here than on Apple - Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Daniel I do like Apple.SE better, but from my experience, questions that are specifically related to Apple products usually do better on Apple.SE. I also just realized that this question was just asked. I was browsing some of the older (at least I thought they were) questions, and came across this one. I told someone else to migrate an old question to Apple and their question has several answers, whereas, on SU, it didn't have any.

Comment: @daviesgeek You will also find pretty much unanswered questions on Apple.SE where there is a readily available answer on SU like [this one](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11433/applescript-open-with-icon/13721#13721). It goes in both directions; during my short excursion to Apple.SE I found quite a few "abandoned" questions. Granted, if you don't get an answer for a week, that might be a reason to migrate. It might also be sufficient to edit to get some attention.

Comment: @Daniel Actually, questions like this get answered pretty quickly on AD.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware device that is not enabled in safe mode (in either Mac OS X or Windows XP) is causing the problem.  Perhaps you could try disabling one or more devices and try again?